# How to bind JTable and Vector?

Tags: java, swing, data-binding, vector, jtable

How to bind a Vector with a JTable ?
I need a JTable and a Vector<> where each press on a JButton
will add a new Object in Vector and add new row and each modification
on cells value of the row will be repercuted on the vector and its objects.

Comment: Read here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DefaultTableModel` does this by default

Take a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) for more details